# Formal arguments of a dynamically created function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, function, typescript

In Javascript you can create a function dynamically, like this:

```
const func = new Function(['arg'], 'console.log(arg)');
```

So that it can be called with the given arguments: `func('Hello')`. However, in Typescript the `Function` constructor seems to accept only one argument, the function body. Is there a way to provide formal arguments to a dynamically generated function?

(Security note: the code is coming from a trustworthy source and what it may contain is verified to be very limited.)

Comment: Just a side note, *Typescript the Function constructor* for this, what are you referring?

Comment: @Rajesh in TS you can do things like `new Function('console.log("Hello")'`, without formal arguments.

Comment: @Rajesh aha, it is using rest form, like `new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b')`. Thanks! If you create an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Function` constructor takes a variable number of strings just like the typescript definition states, with the last one being the function body:

```
new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)
```

This is according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Browser implementations are probably more permissive, but typescript adheres to the spec.

The simplest solution is to call the function as intended:

```
const func = new Function('arg', 'console.log(arg)');
```

Or if you already have the array of arguments:

```
const func = new Function(...['arg'].concat('console.log(arg)'));
```

Comment: Yep, this somehow slipped through me when I was implementing the JS version. Node seems to accept the version with array as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the Function constructor for creating a new function, just assign a function to variable like this:

```
const func = function(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}
```

Assigning a function this way is known as a Function Expression and it is used extensively in JavaScript. Assigning it this way you can add as many arguments as required.

```
const func = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    console.log(arg1);
    console.log(arg2);
    console.log(arg3);
}
```

Comment: I need the function to be created dynamically from a string.